# MySQL - Like + JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation, group-concat

I want to search for a user in my database, and for each, make a JOIN ON another table. Here are my tables:

`USERS`: `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, [...] - Containing user's data

`FRIENDS`: `fan_id`, `idol_id`, [...] - Which user follows which user

Here is my search query, classic:

```
SELECT `id`, `username`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `lang`, `twitter`, `facebook`, `picture`, `regdate`
FROM `users`
WHERE `username` LIKE ?
OR `email` LIKE ?
OR `firstname` LIKE ?
OR `lastname` LIKE ?
OR `twitter` LIKE ?
OR `facebook` LIKE ?
ORDER BY `username`;
```

So now, I want to a get friends table, containing the relationship between the searched user and the user which is asking this.

Here is what I thought about:

```
SELECT `id`, `username`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `lang`, `twitter`, `facebook`, `picture`, `regdate`,
GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT_WS(':', `fan_id`, `idol_id`) SEPARATOR ';'
) AS relations
FROM `friends`, `users`
WHERE (`username` LIKE ?
OR `email` LIKE ?
OR `firstname` LIKE ?
OR `lastname` LIKE ?
OR `twitter` LIKE ?
OR `facebook` LIKE ?)
AND (
(`fan_id` = 100 AND `idol_id` = `id`)
OR
(`fan_id` = `id` AND `idol_id` = 100)
)
ORDER BY `username`;
```

Actually, I want to get in `relations` if the searched user appears as `fan_id` AND the searching user as `idol_id` or the contrary.
But when I search for a user with the first query, I have 2 rows, 2 users (ids = `80` & `125`). With the second query, I have only 1 row (id = `80`) but the `relations` shows `100:80;100:125` which says that I have a half of the query working...

For information, I also want to have a result if there isn't (in `relations`), so I tried `IFNULL(..., 0)` but nothing more.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's really difficult to understand what you actually want. Is fan_id the id of the user that is checking the relationship between themselves and another user? And you want them to see whether the user being searched for is a fan or idol of the user that is doing the search? Why are you the concat-ing these results? Why not just have two columns, one for idol and another for fan and have them be either true or false?

Comment: Yeah, sorry it's bad explained. Actually, I want to search for a user, AND have it's relationships with the user which is searching for a user. Then in PHP, I just have to count the relationships (2 means follow each other, 1 means I have to check who is following)

Comment: I have edited my answer to include another query I came up with for you.

Answer (score 3):

This is based off of a guess of what I think you are aiming for:

```
select users.id,users.firstname,
case 
when CONCAT_WS(';',t1.fans,t2.idols)='' then null
else CONCAT_WS(';',t1.fans,t2.idols)
end as relations
from users left join 
(
select CONCAT_WS(':',fan_id,idol_id) as fans,idol_id
from friends
where fan_id=80
) as t1
on users.id=t1.idol_id
left join
(
select CONCAT_WS(':',fan_id,idol_id) as idols,fan_id
from friends
where idol_id=80
) as t2
on users.id=t2.fan_id
where id=100
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a1cb/1) is the result for a user with id 100 who is searching for a user with id 80.

`where fan_id=80` and `where idol_id=80` needs to be set to the correct id for the user being searched for and `where id=100` can be replaced with the wheres for finding the user doing the searching. Or you can remove all three and get a list of everyone's relations to eachother.

---EDIT---

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25186/6)

This query gives less detail but searches through friends only once and users only once; specifically it no longer holds the ids in the idol and fan columns, rather these columns are either 1 or null. 1 means that the user is that of the other user, so user 125 searches for user 100 and has `fan - null | idol - 1` which means that they are not a fan of user 100 but they are an idol of user 100. The relations column as suggested in my previous comment is either 2 for both a fan and idol, 1 for just one of those, or 0 for neither.

```
select users.id,users.firstname,sum(t1.fan) as fan,sum(t1.idol) as idol,
case 
when t1.fan is null and t1.idol is null then null
else count(*) 
end as relations
from users
left join
(
select fan_id,idol_id,
case when fan_id=100 then 1 end as idol,
case when idol_id=100 then 1 end as fan
from friends
where fan_id=100 or idol_id=100
) as t1
on users.id=t1.fan_id or users.id=t1.idol_id
where firstname like '%user1%'
group by id
```

Four places where you have to change the id of the user being searched for, all the 100s. And the where clause at the bottom can be populated by whatever you want.

Comment: Hey ! I've made a mix between your query and the previous one, the only problem is that when there is no result, it's not `=''` because I still have only one row (2 users has the username LIKE %max%). Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @Max13 I'm sorry but I don't really understand the problem. If there is no relational match then `relations=null`. And what does `2 users has the username LIKE %max%` have to do with it? Are you saying if you get multiple results on the user doing the searching you'll get the wrong result? I'll carry on helping you if you still have a problem and want me to, so just let me know. Also have you considered doing it instead with 3 columns, relation count (2 is following each other, 1 is either a fan or idol, and 0 is neither), and then a fans and idols column which can be null or have the id.

Comment: Yup! This is almost what I'm looking for. Today I do 2 different queries, but if I use yours, with the search (`username LIKE '%user%'`), won't your query be slower that 2 differents ? I would like to combine them (like your query) but I'm afraid of the speed (case + 2 joins)? Thank your for your help.

Comment: @Max13 It difficult for me to say without testing on a larger amount of data, but it is possible. I tested out two queries once where the more complicated one would've made my life a lot easier but it was incredibly slow so I didn't use it. Sometimes using PHP to get the results you want is the right way to go in my opinion. The query as it is searches through friends twice and users once, the `case` is only being applied once though so that shouldn't make much of a diff, and the data is joining on a relatively small amount because it is being filtered out with the `where`s I think.

Comment: I've checked your second sqlfiddle, it's quite like what I need, but except having 3 columns (`fans`, `idols`, `relation`) isn't there a way to get a `CONCAT` of the actual relationships ? Like `80:100;100:80` ? Thank you.

Comment: @Max13 From what I understand you need to know whether the user searching is a fan or idol of another user, so why do you need the format like `80:100;100:80`. If you do have the format like `80:100;100:80` then what would you need the `fans` and `idols` columns for? My first sqlfiddle had the concat like you wanted, so tweaking that one would be the best bet now, but I really don't understand what you are trying to get out of this data.

Comment: Actually, I don't need separated `fans` and `idols`, because I had on mind to explode the `relations` to detemine if it's a fan/idol/both. But you're right, your first query is good, except that I want a search. You're helping me, thanks.

Comment: @Max13 I assumed that's what you were doing, but in my other query you would not need to do an explode because it would tell you if the they are both a fan and idol - `relations = 2`, or just one of those `relations = 1` in which case you then check which column is null, `fan` or `idol`, or neither `relations = 0`. But if you want to stick to your explode idea then that's fine and I'll see what I can do. So what do you mean by wanting a search? The `where id=100` at the bottom can be turned into your `like` searches and then you just need to change the two `where id=80` to the other id.

Comment: Ok then. You were right with your query giving idols/fan/relation. I'll try it with the `LIKE`s, and i'll tell you ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to use the standard `JOIN` syntax than it is to use the obsolete omega-join model that you're using.

In a multiple-table query you should probably qualify your column names.

Start your join with the so-called lead table.  In your case you want a row per user, so start the join with that.

Your long cascade of `OR` criteria in your WHERE will cause your query to perform very poorly.  You may want to consider some sort of FULLTEXT (binary mode) search instead.

Backticks inhibit readability and aren't necessary except when a table or column has the same name as a reserved word.

You have a `GROUP_CONCAT` summarizing function, but no corresponding `GROUP BY` clause, in the query. You need both. (There are allowable linguistic shortcuts in which `GROUP BY` isn't necessary, but you should avoid those when you're debugging things.)

I am trying to figure out your join criteria, but I don't get it. I don't understand what's special about id = 100.  But, is it possible that you want, in the second part of your join, to look for `idol_id = 100` rather than `fan_id = 100`?

```
             (f.fan_id = u.id AND  f.idol_id = 100)
```

What you have doesn't seem logical to this outsider to your project.

I suggest you try this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, 
       u.firstname, u.lastname, 
       u.lang, u.twitter, u.facebook, 
       u.picture, u.regdate,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', f.fan_id, f.idol_id) SEPARATOR ';') AS relations
  FROM users u
  JOIN friends f ON  (                  
             (f.fan_id = 100 AND f.idol_id = u.id)
                OR
             (f.fan_id = u.id AND  f.idol_id = 100)
            )
 WHERE u.username LIKE ?
    OR u.email LIKE ?
    OR u.firstname LIKE ?
    OR u.lastname LIKE ?
    OR u.twitter LIKE ?
    OR u.facebook LIKE ?
 GROUP BY u.id, u.username, 
       u.firstname, u.lastname, 
       u.lang, u.twitter, u.facebook, 
       u.picture, u.regdate
 ORDER BY u.username
```

Comment: I'm just curious, but I've never heard of the old style ANSI SQL-86 JOIN syntax being referred to as an omega-join.  Where did that term come from?

Comment: I don't know if I've read it anywhere. But some colleagues in an old-timey Oracle shop I once worked in called it that.  It may be from the `a.id = b.id(+)` syntax for a left join.

Comment: @OllieJones In order: 1) I will look for `FULLTEXT` when I finish this. 2) Backtips are for my own readability, if it's wrong, I'll remove them. 3) I didn't know about GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY T_T . 4) You're right, I meant `idol_id`. 100 would be the user_id who is searching another user. FINAL) Your query is close to what I'm looking for. But one of our existing user isn't showing because there is no interaction between `100` and the second user. I need a default value. Thank you very much.